# How do I get the manager object for a Model foreign key field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to retrieve the Manager (or Model) for a Django foreign key. This should be straightforward but I can't seem to find the right attribtues.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

Let's say I have the variable modelBInstance and the string "thing" and I want to get ModelA. I've followed (exhaustively, I think) the obvious looking attributes of each object using `getattr`. Either I'm missing something or it's not possible. And I don't think it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:
1. Model instances don't have managers, Model's do.
2. To get the manager, of the foreign key you will have to first reference its class and then reference it manager.

type(getattr(modelBInstance,'thing')).objects would give you access to the manager.

Answer (score 2):

All the relevant information about fields is stored in the `_meta` class of the model. In there, you'll see a `get_field_by_name` method that will return the actual foreign key field. From there, you can get the model it points at via `rel.to`.

```
thing = ModelB._meta.get_field_by_name('thing')[0]
print thing.rel.to
```